# Audio thread SIP Android

Tags: android, sip

I have a connection with `SIP` server(Asterisk), but micro and dynamics doesn't work. Asterisk  kicks client in 31 seconds(Empty RTP thread). Documentation by Google says:

> Android provides an API that supports the Session Initiation Protocol (SIP). This lets you add SIP-based internet telephony features to your applications. Android includes a full SIP protocol stack and integrated call management services that let applications easily set up outgoing and incoming voice calls, without having to manage sessions, transport-level communication, or audio record or playback directly.

**Activity + Receiver**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public String domain = "192.168.10.37";
public String name = "111";
public String password = "123456";
public String sipAddress = "100@192.168.10.37";
public IncomingCallReceiver receiver;
public SipManager sipManager;
public SipProfile sipProfile;
public SipAudioCall call;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.USE_SIP)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.USE_SIP)) {

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.USE_SIP},
                    0);
        }
    }

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("zlotnikov.SIPexample.INCOMING_CALL");
    receiver = new IncomingCallReceiver();
    this.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);

    initManager();
}

private void initManager() {
    if (sipManager == null) {
        sipManager = SipManager.newInstance(this);
    }

}

private void initializeLocalProfile() {
    if (sipProfile != null) {
        closeLocalProfile();
    }
    try {
        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(name, domain);
        builder.setPassword(password);
        builder.setSendKeepAlive(true);
        builder.setAutoRegistration(true);
        sipProfile = builder.build();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("zlotnikov.SIPexample.INCOMING_CALL");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
        SipRegistrationListener listener = new SipRegistrationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRegistering(String s) {
                System.out.println("voip onRegistering " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onRegistrationDone(String s, long l) {
                System.out.println("voip onRegistrationDone " + s + " " + l);
                //initCall();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRegistrationFailed(String s, int i, String s1) {
                System.out.println("voip onRegistrationFailed " + s);
            }
        };
        sipManager.open(sipProfile, pendingIntent, null);
        //sipManager.register(sipProfile, 40, listener);
        sipManager.setRegistrationListener(sipProfile.getUriString(), listener);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SipException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    initializeLocalProfile();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    closeLocalProfile();
}

private void closeLocalProfile() {
    try {
        if (sipProfile != null) {
            sipManager.close(sipProfile.getUriString());
        }
    } catch (Exception ee) {
        ee.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void initCall() {
    try {
        SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
                super.onCallEstablished(call);
                System.out.println("voip onCallEstablished");
                call.startAudio();
                call.setSpeakerMode(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
                super.onCallEnded(call);
                System.out.println("voip onCallEnded");
            }
        };

        call = sipManager.makeAudioCall(sipProfile.getUriString(), sipAddress, listener, 30);

    } catch (SipException e) {
        closeLocalProfile();
        call.close();
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("voip MainActivity Конец соединения");
    }
}

public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SipAudioCall incomingCall = null;
        System.out.println("voip Пришел звонок " + intent.toString());
        try {

            SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onRinging(SipAudioCall call, SipProfile caller) {
                    System.out.println("voip onRinging()");
                    try {
                        startRinging();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        stopRinging();
                        System.out.println("voip onRinging exception");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
                    super.onCallEstablished(call);
                    System.out.println("voip onCallEstablished()");
                    stopRinging();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
                    super.onCallEnded(call);
                    System.out.println("voip onCallEnded()");
                }
            };

            incomingCall = sipManager.takeAudioCall(intent, listener);
            incomingCall.startAudio();
            incomingCall.setSpeakerMode(true);
            /*if (incomingCall.isMuted()) {
                incomingCall.toggleMute();
            }*/

            //call = incomingCall;

            incomingCall.answerCall(30);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (incomingCall != null) {
                incomingCall.close();
                System.out.println("voip IncomingCallReceiver конец соединения");
            }
        }

    }

    private synchronized void startRinging() {
        long[] pattern = {0, 1000, 1000};
        ((Vibrator) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(pattern, 0);
        Uri defaultRingtoneUri = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), defaultRingtoneUri);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mediaPlayer.start();

    }

    private synchronized void stopRinging() {
        ((Vibrator) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE))
                .cancel();
        if (mediaPlayer != null || mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
}
```

}

**Manifest**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="zlotnikov.sipexample">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sip.voip" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".MainActivity$IncomingCallReceiver" android:label="Call Receiver" />
</application>
```